# vectorize a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a dataframe in the tidy format such as

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c',3: 'a', 4: 'b', 5: 'c'},

                   'B': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5,3: 1, 4: 3, 5: 5},

                   'C': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6,3: 2, 4: 4, 5: 6}})
```

I made a function that in this case would map the codes 'a', 'b', 'c' in column 'A' to the observables in columns 'B' and 'C'.

The function is

```
def vectorize(df):
    indexdict={}
    for code in df['A'].unique():
        indexdict.update({'A':code})
        transpose = df.T
        value_dict ={}
        for item in transpose.iloc[1]:
            for value in transpose.iloc[2]:
                value_dict.update({item:value})
    indexdict.update(value_dict)
    indexdict = {str(key):value for key,value in indexdict.items()}
    df = pd.DataFrame(indexdict,index=[0])
    df.set_index('A', inplace=True)
    return df
```

I want to get a dataframe with all a, b,c codes with observables. However, when I do the function only returns the last entry. like this

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD1M6.png)

What am I doing wrong and is there a better way of doing this. The output is what I want but instead of just a single value I want all values for a, b, and c

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need to do. Why is the expected output `6 6 6` for `1 3 5`.

Comment: I'm also not sure I understand what you need to do. My guess is you need a pivot table: `df.pivot_table(index='A',columns='B',values='C',aggfunc='mean',fill_value=0)`

Comment: So basically, column 'A' contains a code for an item being made. Column 'B' is the step number (in a sequence of steps) in the making process, column 'C' is the actual instruction on that step. I Want to only instead of having the item being made as a row and the step number as a column then the entries would be the instructions

Comment: eg. I am cooking meat and veggies. the instructions would be
```
'A'           'B'   '     C'
Meat        1          defrost
Meat        2          Clean
Meat        3          Cook
Veggies    1         Clean
Veggies    2         Chop
Veggies    3          Cook
````
Then my df would just be
```
food          1           2        3
meat         defrost  Clean Cook
veggies     Clean    Chop   Cook
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out by using the solution from @natnij but for strings

```
df.pivot_table(index='A',columns='B',values='C',aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

thank you